# mysql - Compare current timestamp against two time ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a database which holds information about daily functions' opening times.

Usually, the database only has the function ID and the opening times, but here I have the function name as an example.

```
Table: opening_times
| function_id |   function_name  |  day_open  |  day_close |  eve_open  |  eve_close |
|-------------|------------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|    1        | Charity Function | 1357027200 | 1357056000 | 1357063200 | 1357081200 |
```

**I'd like to write an SQL statement, which sees whether the function has:**

- Not yet opened for day
- Daytime Open
- Lunch Break
- Evening Open
- Closed for day

This will obviously have to compare the current time[stamp] against the two date ranges I have stored in the database.

Could someone help me to achieve this. Once I have the syntax, I will learn!

I can do a standard IF statement, to see whether this is between **ONE** time-range, but this obviously doesn't achieve the result I need:

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT 

CASE IF UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN ot.`day_open` AND ot.`day_close`

THEN  'Within daytime open range'
ELSE 'Not in daytime open range' END as open_status
FROM opening_times ot
```

Comment: Thanks, but the aim was to find out if the function is: Not yet opened for day,
Daytime Open,
Lunch Break,
Evening Open or
Closed for day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) < ot.`day_open`
            THEN 'Function has not started'
        WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN ot.`day_open` AND ot.`day_close`
            THEN 'function open'
        WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN ot.`day_close` AND ot.`eve_open`
            THEN 'Mid-Day Break'        
        WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN ot.`eve_open` AND ot.`eve_close`
            THEN 'Evening Open'
        WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > ot.`eve_close`
            THEN 'Closed for day'
END AS function_open_status
FROM opening_times ot WHERE ot.function_id=1
```